# Missing classes Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

Here is my `POM.xml`

```
...

  <properties>
    <spring.webflow.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


...

  <repositories>

   <repository>

      <id>spring-snapshots</id>

      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>

      <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>

   </repository>
...
</project>
```

The error is:

```
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
EnableWebSecurity cannot be resolved to a type (Annotation)
...
```

These should be in the package:
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration

I've done a `mvn clean install -U`, but this didn't solve the problem. Any Ideas if I'm missing some dependencies or any incompatibility between these dependencies?

## I've found a weird scenario:

After adding these dependencies into my pom, I can't see them in my eclipse project > Maven Dependencies?!

King Regards,

Comment: You need to add `spring-security-web` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

> Missing classes Spring Security

These two dependency used for [Spring security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)

```
<!-- Spring security -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>    
</dependency>
```